# Using Range Function

Tags: python, range

My goal is to make a program that takes an input (Battery_Capacity) and ultimately spits out a list of the (New_Battery_Capacity) and the Number of (Cycle) it takes for it ultimately to reach maximum capacity of 80.

```
Cycle = range (160)
Charger_Rate = 0.5 * Cycle
Battery_Capacity = float(raw_input("Enter Current Capacity:"))
New_Battery_Capacity = Battery_Capacity + Charger_Rate

if Battery_Capacity < 0:
    print 'Battery Reading Malfunction (Negative Reading)'

elif Battery_Capacity > 80:
    print 'Battery Reading Malfunction (Overcharged)'

elif float(Battery_Capacity) % 0.5 !=0:
    print 'Battery Malfunction (Charges Only 0.5 Interval)'

while Battery_Capacity >= 0 and Battery_Capacity < 80:
    print New_Battery_Capacity
```

I was wondering why my Cycle = range(160) isn't working in my program?

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: How is it not working? You don't appear to be doing anything with `Cycle` after you assign it to `range(160)`.

Comment: For starters you use `Cycle` in `Charger_Rate = 0.5 * Cycle` before you give `Cycle` a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you have the first two lines in the wrong order. You need a "Cycle" variable to exist before you can use it.

You'll still get an error when you swap them, though. You can't multiply a list by a float. A list comprehension is more what you want:

```
Charger_Rate = [i * .5 for i in Cycle]
```

As far as I can tell, the `range(160)` part is fine.